# How do I call a Django function on button click?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to write a Django application and I am stuck at how I can call a view function when a button is clicked.

In my template, I have a link button as below, when clicked it takes you to a different webpage:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="{{ column_3_item.link_for_item }}">Check It Out</a>
```

When the button is clicked, I also want to call a Django view function (along with re-direct to a target website). The view function increments the value in the database which stores the number of times the button is clicked.

The `column_3_item.link_for_item` is a link to an external website (e.g. *www.google.com*). Right now when that button is clicked, it opens a new window which takes you to the google website.

What I would like to do is to call a Django view function also when the button is clicked which updates the database without refreshing the page. How I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code calls the view function at whatever `column_3_item.link_for_item` is mapped to in your urlconf.

Comment: adding to Daniel's comment: if you need to click -> "real time" update the couter, without refreshing the page, you may need to rewrite your question. If you have a view pointing to that link, you already have what you need

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the `column_3_item.link_for_item` is a link to an external website (example:- www.google.com). Right now when that button is clicked, it opens a new window which takes to google website. what i would like to do is to call a django view function also when the button is clicked which updates the database without refreshing the page.

Comment: have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html

Comment: you can do it in many ways, but if you do not want to reload/change the page I think you have to rely on javascript (e.g. making an ajax call to the view that updates the counter from the same <a> tag you use for opening the new page). Is using javascript an issue?

Comment: @furins - Could you please give an example how i can do it with javascript. Sorry to ask this, i am just new to web development.

Comment: [Read the Django tutorial, it has all the information you need](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

here is a pure-javascript, minimalistic approach. I use JQuery but you can use any library ([or even no libraries at all](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/)).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>An example</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function call_counter(url, pk) {
                window.open(url);
                $.get('YOUR_VIEW_HERE/'+pk+'/', function (data) {
                    alert("counter updated!");
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="call_counter('http://www.google.com', 12345);">
            I update object 12345
        </button>
        <button onclick="call_counter('http://www.yahoo.com', 999);">
            I update object 999
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Alternative approach**

Instead of placing the JavaScript code, you can change your link in this way:

```
<a target="_blank" 
    class="btn btn-info pull-right" 
    href="{% url YOUR_VIEW column_3_item.pk %}/?next={{column_3_item.link_for_item|urlencode:''}}">
    Check It Out
</a>
```

and in your `views.py`:

```
def YOUR_VIEW_DEF(request, pk):
    YOUR_OBJECT.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(views=F('views')+1)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I used the alternative approach and it worked perfectly as expected.

Comment: The point of using Django is to eliminate using other languages. I'm sorry for js but if you're using Django when a button is clicked we want to trigger using Django but not js. Please help me!

Comment: @KuneMohith then please follow the alternative approach, it does not require javascript. Apart from that, I do not believe that the point of Django is to eliminate using other languages. You cannot run "django" (python) on client side.

Comment: `HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next')))` is containing one ')' to much at the end.

Comment: @The_spider fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 27):

There are 2 possible solutions that I personally use

1.without using form

```
 <button type="submit" value={{excel_path}} onclick="location.href='{% url 'downloadexcel' %}'" name='mybtn2'>Download Excel file</button>
```

2.Using Form

```
<form action="{% url 'downloadexcel' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}


 <button type="submit" name='mybtn2' value={{excel_path}}>Download results in Excel</button>
 </form>
```

Where urls.py should have this

```
path('excel/',views1.downloadexcel,name="downloadexcel"),
```

Answer (score 5):

The following answer could be helpful for the first part of your question:

[Django: How can I call a view function from template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599035/django-how-can-i-call-a-view-function-from-template/19761466#19761466)