# Django: How can I call a view function from template?

Tags: django, templates, view

I have a question on how to call a view function from a template HTML button? Like an onclick function?
Here is the template:

```
<input id="submit" type="button" onclick="xxx" method="post" value="Click" />
```

And the views.py is:

```
def request_page(request):
    ...do something...
    return render_to_response("/directory.html", {})
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One option is, you can wrap the `submit` button with a `form`

Something like this:

```
<form action="{% url path.to.request_page %}" method="POST">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Click" />
</form>
```

(remove the `onclick` and `method`)

If you want to load a specific part of the page, without page reload - you can do

```
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Click" data_url/>
```

and on a `submit` listener

```
$(function(){
     $('form').on('submit', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             method: $(this).attr('method'),
             success: function(data){ $('#target').html(data) }
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: Yeah.. thats what the ajax submit is doing. your question was unclear, so i added both the answers

Comment: I wonder is there any way for doing multithreadings in Django? Here is the questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601698/can-django-do-multi-thread-works

Comment: [Django-Notification](https://github.com/pinax/django-notification) could be what you are looking for. What does this have to do with this question anyways ?

Comment: @karthikr you'll have to change your input in the first snippet to type="submit"

Comment: Where do I put the code for the submit listener?

Answer (score 114):

Assuming that you want to get a value from the user input in html textbox whenever the user clicks 'Click' button, and then call a python function (mypythonfunction) that you wrote inside mypythoncode.py. Note that "btn" class is defined in a css file.

inside templateHTML.html:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
 <input type="text" value="8" name="mytextbox" size="1"/>
 <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

inside view.py:

```
import mypythoncode

def request_page(request):
  if(request.GET.get('mybtn')):
    mypythoncode.mypythonfunction( int(request.GET.get('mytextbox')) )
return render(request,'myApp/templateHTML.html')
```

Comment: This is a very good answer - surprised no more votes... Have you used this in your own projects?

Comment: I am glad it was useful. Yes I have a project uploaded at Github where I used it. https://github.com/MahshidZ/ArchivIT

Comment: Take care, GET and HEAD request should be safe/idenpotent. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: What about {% csrf_token %} after input ?

Comment: How do I have to change the url file?

Comment: As @Danielius mentioned, I had to add `{% csrf_token %}` inside the `<form>` tag. 

Additionally, I used `<form method="POST" action="">` and found success by invoking `request.POST.get("buttonname")`, in case this helps anyone else. I did this because it was confusing having the `GET` request method, then also invoking the `.get()` method.

Answer (score 12):

How about this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'url-name'%}">Button-Text</a>
```

The class is including bootstrap styles for primary button.

Answer (score 5):

you can put the input inside a form like this:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#send', function(){
            $('#hid').val(data)
            document.forms["myForm"].submit();
        })
    })
</script>

<form id="myForm" action="/request_page url/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="hid" name="hid"/>
</form>
<div id="send">Send Data</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

For deleting all data:

**HTML FILE**

```
  class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'delete_product'%}">Delete
```

Put the above code in an anchor tag. (the a tag!)

**url.py**

```
path('delete_product', views.delete_product, name='delete_product')]
```

**views.py**

```py
def delete_product(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        dest = Racket.objects.all()
        dest.delete()
        return render(request, "admin_page.html")
```

Answer (score 4):

For example, a logout button can be written like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href={% url 'logout'%}">Logout</button>
```

Where logout endpoint:

```
#urls.py:
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
```