# Range Slider in Django

Tags: django, html, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a Range Slider in my template. I want to call a function in my view on Range Slider value change.

```
index.html
<input id="slider1" type="range" value="3" min="1" max="20" step="1" />
```

I am using a button and text also I took help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599035/django-how-can-i-call-a-view-function-from-template/19761466#19761466)

Python 2.7.10 Django 1.9

Comment: I want value of slider also so as I can change my calculation in function which is defined in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have `call_view(request)` to call...

```
<input type="range" ... onchange="callFun(this.value)">
```

Note: I used `fetch`

```
function callFun(value) {
    fetch('call_your_url/?value='+ value).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
    }
}
```

In your view function...

```
def call_view(request):
    request.GET.get('value')
    return HttpResponse("success")
```

Comment: No...call_view is just a function how can it call directly from HTML

Comment: let's say I have an app 'myApp' and myApp.views has a class myClass and that class has a function call_view. Now what am i supposed to provide there

Comment: I thought you have function based views... Now you are telling class based views ah ? Try with simple function based view then try with class...

Comment: It actually not that so much easy to get the GET parameters... but wait I will update my answer...

Comment: no....can you specify here what is url to be put inside fetch...I am not getting value of slider in views

Comment: Can you look into your `urls.py` and tell what are the urls you have ...

Comment: url(r'temp/',ClusterPlot.renderTemplate,name='temp')

Comment: This is getting harder.. shall we go my way.. Just put this in your urls...  `url(r'call-view/', views.call_view),`

Comment: and see my answer there is call_view function please copy paste it in your views.py file.. do now...

Comment: And inside the `fetch('call-view/', ... `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118979/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-utkarsh).