# How to call a django view function based on its namespace and fun name from js?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

To call a Django view from HTML we use the following:

```
"{% url 'namespace: view_fun' %}"
```

But how to do this from Javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: hope this will helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17599126/3551268

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One hacky way to do it would be to include following script in your template that references the javascript file.

```
<script>
    var fun_url = "{% url 'namespace: view_fun' %}";
</script>
```

And then expecting this `fun_url` variable in your referenced javascript file.

Comment: Does not solve what I want. I need this in JS script which is a separate file. It should fit somehow in the following: window.location.href = ...

Comment: It does solve it. You can't treat js files as templates, but you *can* share js variables in the same DOM.