# Call Django on HTML button click

Tags: html, django, function, sorting

I'm trying to make a basic sort function for a Django project, but I don't know how to call the sort function when I click the 'sort' button

Django view:

```
def sort_btn(request):
if request.GET.get('sort-btn'):
    cits = Citizen.objects.all().order_by('name')
return render_to_response(request, 'civil_reg/index.html', {'cits': cits})
```

HTML button:

```
<button name="sort-btn" id="sort-btn">sort</button>
```

Comment: this is lead to KeyError since there is no sort-btn value was passed in the request. You need to atleast create a html input control with a value and send a request

Comment: This answer would help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599035/django-how-can-i-call-a-view-function-from-template/19761466#19761466)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you need to wrap your `<button>` with `<form>` tag, as following snippet:

```
<form action='actionUrl' method='GET'>
<button type='submit'> sort me</button>
</form>
```

and in your `urls.py` module you should point the actionUrl with specific view from the `views.py` module as follow:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(actionUrl, views.yourSort),
]
```

you should more read about request lifecycle on Django:

1. user submit request
2. Django tries to get the first match between request's URL and routes defined in `urls.py`
3. the request is passed to the matched view
4. the view get executed, usually this some model processing
5. a response (template) is returned by the view as `HttpResponse`

Comment: Thanks so much. 
One question, now I made an entirely new webpage ('action URL') for sorting by name, will I have to do another three pages if -say- I wanted to make another three sort functions? Or is there a better way?

Comment: you are welcome, no you do not have to create three templates, you just assign a different value in each view to  your 'cits' key in the context object. as clarification: {'cits': byNamecits} {'cits': byAreacits}...etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your program but my implementation is the full as it is that worked.

```
<button name="button" type="submit" onclick="location.href='{% url "actionUrl" %}'"> Send</button>
```

I am trying to call a function in views named "sendEmail"

```
path('actionUrl/', views.sendEmail,name='actionUrl')
```

And above one is the line which I included in urls file.