# Django admin : How to call an action on a click of custom button?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have a django admin view displaying a list of orders. I have added a custom button, which when clicked should perform a certain action.

[image]

So I have a function defined in my services.py file as :

```
def penalty(order):
  #Do something
```

So, how should I call this function when **Penalty** is clicked. I can create a view, but how to call it?

Comment: Is this create using Django form or any other front-end technology?

Comment: Yes, it is created using Django Form.

Answer (score 3):

All u need is here:

> https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41

Follow the easy steps and your ready to go.
Many others all around the web.

Answer (score 1):

The following answers could be helpful for solving your problems.

- [How do I call a Django function on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341285/how-do-i-call-a-django-function-on-button-click)
- [Django: How can I call a view function from template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599035/django-how-can-i-call-a-view-function-from-template)
- [Call Django on HTML button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438575/call-django-on-html-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a URL like this to call a function

```
     def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path(
                'penalty/<int:id>',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.penalty),
                name='penalty'
            )
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls
```

from a button click in Django admin