# Django admin button for fields to trigger action

Tags: django, forms, admin, django-4.1

In the Django admin change form of my model I would like to be able to add a button next to any field. Clicking this button should call some function with the current form data as input. Once the function returns, the Django admin form should be updated by the return values of the function.

I know of one way to add a button at the very bottom of the admin model change pape, right below the save button, but this is not what I want. The button should be right next to the specific input field.

Currently, I have no idea where to start and conceptionally how this is achieved.

I googled a lot, but couldn't find a solution yet. I thought of creating a new form widget that I could assign to an inputfield, but buttons in forms are not available in django.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Does this help with your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593064/django-admin-how-to-call-an-action-on-a-click-of-custom-button