# Trouble getting my HTML button linked to a Python function using Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am attempting to take data from an HTML page form hosted on Django's localhost development server and send it to a database in Models. I'm attempting to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761466/12352379) solution, but I'm not sure how to link the function to the reference to the HTML in views.py. Here's my views.py currently:

```
# djangotemplates/example/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView # Import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pathfinder.models import characterTable

def addCharacter(sUserID, sPlayerName, sRace, sPlayerClass, sStr, sCon, sDex, sInt, sWis, sCha):
    c = characterTable()
    c.userID=sUserID
    c.playerName = sPlayerName
    #... rest of fields go here
    c.save()

def request_page(request):
    if(request.GET.get('mybtn')):
        userID = 'testUser'
        addCharacter(userID, string(request.GET.get('characterName')), string(request.GET.get('race')), string(request.GET.get('class')), string(request.GET.get('characterName')), string(request.GET.get('strength')), string(request.GET.get('dexterity')), string(request.GET.get('constitution')), string(request.GET.get('intelligence')), string(request.GET.get('wisdom')), string(request.GET.get('charisma')))


# Add the two views we have been talking about  all this time :)
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "about.html"
```

And here is the HTML, in my templates folder:

```
<!-- djangotemplates/example/templates/index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Go Home</a>
  <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About This Site</a>

  <form name = "characterForm" id = "characterForm" method = "get" action = "#">
  Character Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="characterName" id ="characterName">
  <br>

  Race:<br>
  <select name = "race" id = "race">
    <option value = "human"> Human </option>
    <option value = "elf"> Elf </option>
    <option value = "dwarf"> Dwarf </option>
    <option value = "gnome"> Gnome </option>
    <option value = "halfling"> Halfling </option>
    <option value = "halfElf"> Half-Elf </option>
    <option value = "halfOrc"> Half-Orc </option>
  </select>
  <br>

  Class:<br>
  <select name = "class" id = "class" onchange="changePic()">
    <option value = "fighter"> Fighter </option>
    <option value = "rogue"> Rogue </option>
    <option value = "wizard"> Wizard </option>
  </select>
  <br>

  Strength:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "strength">
  <br>

  Dexterity:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "dexterity">
  <br>

  Constitution:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "constitution">
  <br>

  Intelligence:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "intelligence">
  <br>

  Wisdom:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "wisdom">
  <br>

  Charisma:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "charisma">
  <br>

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="mybtn">

  <br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My issue is that if I hardcode addCharacter to fire with dummy parameters right after

> template_name = "index.html"

in views.py, it adds the dummy parameters just fine, I just can't seem to figure out how to get my form button to fire off the python functions in views.py when I click it. This has held me up for quite a while, and after hours upon hours of sifting through documentation, examples, and answered questions, I still can't figure it out.

EDIT: my characterTable in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class characterTable(models.Model):
    userID = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    playerName = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    race = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    playerClass = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    strength = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    dexterity = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    constitution = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    intelligence = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    wisdom = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    charisma = models.CharField(max_length = 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.userID + ": " + self.playerName )
```

Comment: Hi @nunzio, I'm gonna look into it to you, one moment :)

Comment: Could you please provider your characterTable model @nunzio?

Comment: @EliakinCosta Sorry for the delay, I just edited the original post to include it, I really appreciate that you're willing to take a look!

Answer (score 0):

You do need to change your form method to POST as you are submitting data. After that, you should implement post method within your view as [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) inherits from [View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View), it works just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Go Home</a>
  <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About This Site</a>

  <form name = "characterForm" id = "characterForm" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  Character Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="characterName" id ="characterName">
  <br>

  Race:<br>
  <select name = "race" id = "race">
    <option value = "human"> Human </option>
    <option value = "elf"> Elf </option>
    <option value = "dwarf"> Dwarf </option>
    <option value = "gnome"> Gnome </option>
    <option value = "halfling"> Halfling </option>
    <option value = "halfElf"> Half-Elf </option>
    <option value = "halfOrc"> Half-Orc </option>
  </select>
  <br>

  Class:<br>
  <select name = "class" id = "class" onchange="changePic()">
    <option value = "fighter"> Fighter </option>
    <option value = "rogue"> Rogue </option>
    <option value = "wizard"> Wizard </option>
  </select>
  <br>

  Strength:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "strength">
  <br>

  Dexterity:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "dexterity">
  <br>

  Constitution:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "constitution">
  <br>

  Intelligence:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "intelligence">
  <br>

  Wisdom:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "wisdom">
  <br>

  Charisma:<br>
  <input type = "number" name = "charisma">
  <br>

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="mybtn">

  <br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
...
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        userID = 'testUser'
        addCharacter(
            userID,
            str(request.POST.get('characterName')),
            str(request.POST.get('race')),
            str(request.POST.get('class')),
            str(request.POST.get('strength')),
            str(request.POST.get('dexterity')),
            str(request.POST.get('constitution')),
            str(request.POST.get('intelligence')),
            str(request.POST.get('wisdom')),
            str(request.POST.get('charisma'))
        )

        return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```

P.S. Please consider using Django Forms, it will save you a lot of time and effort. You can find how to implement it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the question as solved :) @nunzio