# Django: Update specific part of template by button click

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a text field

```html
<input type="text" value="This is a test." name="mytextbox" size="10"/>
```

and separated from that a button

```html
<button type = "button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <font size="1">Run</font>
</button>
```

that should update a list **and** update the value of the text field itself.

Sometimes `forms` are used in this context, but I would have to wrap the `forms` tag around the whole template when the input and button are separated on the screen.

Since I am relatively new to Django, I would like to know the best
strategy to solve the problem.

- a) Reload the complete page template with changed arguments/context
- b) Create a html template of the specific part that extends the main template and only try to render/update this one.
- c)  Do something smarter.

There are some answers in a (much older) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599035/django-how-can-i-call-a-view-function-from-template) from 8 years ago but I am interested in the state-of-the-art solution.

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked post is probably the best approach. You'd need javascript to update the field value, so that makes most sense.

Comment: Is it not possible to receive the data from the field value and render the text-field again with a new default value?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to reload the page you could just pass the value to a view by making the field part of a form.