# How can I click a button in python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm looking for a way to click buttons and follow links in pyhton. Or essentially run the javascript function in this tag. I'm trying to use robobrowser but its not working.

```
 <a id="h_w_PC_ctl07_lnkCheckCoupon" class="btnCheckCoupon" title="Check" href="javascript:__doPostBack('h$w$PC$ctl07$lnkCheckCoupon','')"></a>
```

Thats the html from the site.

Comment: Selenium is probably the easiest.

Comment: For simple graphical interface such as buttons you can use the tkinter module that is always installed with python (warning: depending on the version of python the spelling may be with a 'T' instead of the 't'). the 'ttk' submodule is also interesting.

Comment: I suggest Twill for Python. Pretty simple and useful library. http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html docs are pretty shallow but google for more tutorials.

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341285/how-to-call-a-django-function-on-button-click

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341285/how-to-call-a-django-function-on-button-click

Answer (score 1):

Selenium will allow you to interact with websites using python and perform actions such as clicking a button.

To install selenium use the following command:
**pip install selenium** (this is assuming you have pip installed)

After selenium is installed you must download a web driver. If you plan to automate a google chrome web browser the link for the download can be found here http://chromedriver.chromium.org/