# JavaScript snippet not working in Django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

It's been a while since I did Django and I found an example of calling a view from a button that I needed:

[How do I call a Django function on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341285/how-do-i-call-a-django-function-on-button-click)

I built my template to match the example given:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tournament Registration</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function register() {
        alert("Hi")
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <p>{{ tournament.name }}</p>
    <p>Start time: {{ tournament.start_time }}</p>

    <button onclick="register">Register</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

At first I just wanted it to pop an alert box so I know it's working at all. When I click the button however, nothing happens, and I get no error message in console. Am I able to call script tags in a Django template, or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: `onclick="register()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been programming with Django for so long that you're forgetting that Javascript still requires the pesky brackets in templates. :)  No worries, as I do it too.

`<button onclick="register">Register</button>` 
needs to be

`<button onclick="register()">Register</button>` and your code will work fine. 
`