# Running django view/function on button click

Tags: python, django

I have the following button: `<a class="btn btn-success">Accept</a>`. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341285/how-do-i-call-a-django-function-on-button-click) previous stack overflow question, I want to call my view after the button is clicked, but I can not seem to get it to work.

What I have tried: Using AJAX, treating button like a form, requesting post data, but this does not seem to work.

How can I make it so when my button is clicked, I call the bellow view?

```
def acceptdonation(request, pk):
    Donation.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(views=F('views')+1)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next')))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your template link to the view you want:

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:myview' %}" class="btn btn-success">Accept</a>
```

Of course you can also pass a `pk` or other data to the url if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post a form to a view you can use this:

```
function submitToView() {
    var formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('some_variable', 'abc'); 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
  
        abc = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    
      }
    }
  
    xhr.open('POST', '/my_view/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
```

Please consider adding your javascript with html and your urls.py

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but I was wondering if I could do this without using javascript? In the example stack overflow question I included, someone was able to do it with a default django url

Comment: sure, share your code, it will facilitate